# A phrase with adjective + noun

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I am following some repositories. (I am a programmer).
I want to call them "followed repositories". Is that correct?

Comment: Idiomatically, ***monitored*** or ***tracked*** is more likely than ***followed*** here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can meaningfully call them that. Here is one example of that use:

([Description of a bug](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4862/followed-repositories-bug)): *When you revoke access to a team[,] followed repositories still show up in the master list.* (I added the comma as a correction to the referenced text.)